# Check if none of list items have certain text

Tags: jquery, html

I need to check whether a list of items have a certain text. If that text is not present in ALL of them, the add a new element

What I achieved so far is check if each of the element have that text, but this is not what I need... How can I check ALL of the `li` and if the text is not there add the new element?

This is my code:

```
$("#evTypes li").each(function() {
     var typeName = $(this).text();
     if(typeName == "Events") {
        $("#evTypes").prepend("<p class='studentRun'>Event</p>");
     }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:contains` selector along with `length` for this:

```
if ($('#evTypes li:contains("Events")').length === 0)
  $("#evTypes").prepend('<p class="studentRun">Event</p>');
```

Comment: This is adding "Event" for each element that doesn't contain "Events". What I need is to add "Event" just once, only if none of the LI have the word "Events"

Comment: `What I need is to add "Event" just once, only if none of the LI have the word "Events"` that is what this code does: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/2fcL7gns/. If it's not doing that for you then there is an underlying issue somewhere. If you can add your HTML to the question I can help you debug it

Comment: You're right, there was a bug in my code. Thanks for this